# Unable to loop through JSON returned from AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following JSON returned in a variable called `data`

```
 [ 
   {"Id": 10004, "HEAD_NAME": "avcc"}, 
   {"Id": 10040, "HEAD_NAME": "tyiiio jj"}, 
   {"Id": 10059, "HEAD_NAME": "errr"}
 ]
```

I am trying to loop through the collection using `$.each` but I am running into problems where the alert is showing undefined.

```
var url = "<?= base_url(); ?>report/get_value";
var data_sent = {'tab_value': tab_value};
$.post(url, data_sent, function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            console.log("Head value : "+item.HEAD_NAME);
        });
    });
```

Solution : add eval(data)

Code after edit :

```
  $.each(eval(data.replace(/[\r\n]/, "")), function(i, item) {
            console.log("Head value : "+item.head);return false;
        });
```

Comment: Does your `data.result` result shows the above json?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because there is no `result` array in the data structure you're returning. You can also access the object in the iteration using the `item` argument you defined in the `$.each()` handler function. Try this:

```js
var data = [ 
  { "Id": 10004, "HEAD_NAME": "avcc" }, 
  { "Id": 10040, "HEAD_NAME": "tyiiio jj" }, 
  { "Id": 10059, "HEAD_NAME": "errr" }
]

// inside the $.post callback:
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  console.log("Head value : " + item.HEAD_NAME);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also note that you don't need jQuery to loop through an array. You can use the native `forEach()` method instead, like this:

```js
var data = [ 
  { "Id": 10004, "HEAD_NAME": "avcc" }, 
  { "Id": 10040, "HEAD_NAME": "tyiiio jj" }, 
  { "Id": 10059, "HEAD_NAME": "errr" }
]

data.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log("Head value : " + item.HEAD_NAME);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am getting following error :
Solution 1  : Head value : undefined

Solution 2  : report:337 Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

Comment: I have no idea what's causing the first error. The second error is most likely because you're not putting this code within the callback of the AJAX request, or because the response is not in the format you're expecting it to be.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    console.log("Head value : "+data[i].HEAD_NAME);
});
```

Update your foreach loop to read like this

Answer (score 0):

You dont have node "result" in your json. change `data.result` to `data` and it will fix your problem

```js
var data = [ 
   {"Id": 10004, "HEAD_NAME": "avcc"}, 
   {"Id": 10040, "HEAD_NAME": "tyiiio jj"}, 
   {"Id": 10059, "HEAD_NAME": "errr"}
 ];

  // console.log(data);
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  console.log("Head value : " + data[i].HEAD_NAME);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you can also use `item` instead of `data[i]`

```js
var data = [ 
   {"Id": 10004, "HEAD_NAME": "avcc"}, 
   {"Id": 10040, "HEAD_NAME": "tyiiio jj"}, 
   {"Id": 10059, "HEAD_NAME": "errr"}
 ];

  // console.log(data);
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  console.log("Head value : " + item.HEAD_NAME);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have changed data.result to data but still getting undefined error. Is this because of jquery version ?

Comment: did you remove [i] after data (in the console.log)? it you did it might be the problem, if not send your new code

Comment: your code is working,. are you sure you are calling jQuey, do you see the jQuery file in your console?